# .Net Core 2.0 Web Application deploy on IIS shows only blank page

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-core-2.0

I'm developing my first ever .Net core 2.0 web api project and wanted to deploy on my local server IIS. I have installed DotNetCore WebHosting Bundle and added a new application pool with "No Managed Code" option.

And then I copy my published files to IIS webroot folder and create new web site by addressing the physical path to my project folder under IIS webroot. And then I tried to open the site for example "http://localhost:8088/api/city" and it always shows blank page.

Please kindly advise what am I needed to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that EF DbContext is not using the connection string I set but instead it's using IIS AppPool sql login and happening SQL login failure.

And I figured out that removing security attributes in the SQL connection string of my project solved the problem.

Comment: Please how did you do this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: For a quick solve, you can create new user as IIS sql user and assign to your db.